# Redirect customer to login page (with other signup plugin) if user not logged in when proceeding to checkout

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, filters, hooks, redirect

I use "Digits (WordPress Mobile Number Signup and Login)" for signup by email & SMS ;
when non logged in user proceed to checkout , want to redirect to signup form of Digits (not usual woocommerce signup).

In case already logged-in users, they should go following the next step in the checkout process as normal.

appreciate if anybody help.

Comment: in woocommerce -> settings -> Accounts & Privacy, you can unckeck "Allow customers to place orders without an account "

Comment: thanks; I have already done but only one message is displayed (login is required) ; so need auto redirect to login page url or shortcode. if add link of login page there, it shows below the checkout page for logged in user too.

Answer (score 0):

I find and use below code for when user in cart page and cart not empty:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'dj_redirect_checkout');
function dj_redirect_checkout($url) {
     global $woocommerce;
     if(is_cart() && !is_user_logged_in() ){
          $checkout_url = 'digits login url';
     }
     else{
         $checkout_url='https://yoursite.com/checkout/';
     }
     return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I use a plugin called "Digits" and two of its addons called : Lock page & One click login/signup. After istalling these plugins, I have locked checkout page using plugins settings. so when a users heads to checkout page, a popup appears, and requires user to login using their mobile phone number. after successful login/register, the checkout process begins.

Answer (score 0):

Just for those who want to lock the checkout page and prompt a login window to the user, use the code below. No extra addons needed for Digits plugin.

```
// if the user is not logged in, return him to login before checkout
add_action('template_redirect', 'check_if_logged_in');
function check_if_logged_in() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() ) {
        $url = site_url('/checkout/?login=true&back=home');
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit;
    }
}
```